# Finding a ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I findViewById for the following XML?

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I need it to set a list adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax for an id *(not sure if a colon is allowed inside the id name)*. Usually these list ids are `@android:id/list` *(e.g. in a Preference- or ListActivity)*, or `@+id/list` for your own ids.

Comment: This question is bad because it shows little research was done on the part of the poster. A quick google search would have found the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML must look like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView_Name"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

in your code:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Name);
```

Comment: please be careful with formatting.  Backticks are for inline highlighting.  Highlight code and click the curly brackets to format code blocks ;)

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer but the OP failing to recognize your effort

Answer (score 0):

This basic example shows you how to use an ArrayAdapter with a ListView. You should really need to ever actually mess with the ListView itself, just the elements that are put in it.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: To be a bit more constructive here: Answers should be understandable without links. Summarize the important part of the link and use it to give the OP a place to research more. Why? Because links can be down temporarily or dead at all *(yes even the official doc, see the kernel.org disaster at the moment)*. Remember that you not only give the OP an answer, you are also helping a few invisible search engine users. If you only want to post a link, post as a comment instead.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum you should edit your answer to be more informative rather than saying "fair enough".

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById(android.R.id.list)`

The ids prefixed with `android:` are all accessible under `android.R.id`. Similarly `@android:drawable`are accessible as `android.R.drawable`, etc...